# How to add elements from a JSON array to a grid using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

I have a `JSON` array in a file `data.json` which is as :

```
var info = [{
"place": "Turkey",
"username": "jhon"
}, {
"place": "Dubai",
"username": "bruce"
}, {
"place": "Italy",
"username": "Wayne"
}];
```

I am able to access these using a loop and check with the help of an alert box.. However, I wish to display the contents in the form of a table. I could use `JavaScript` or as somebody suggested to me I could also use `Angular.js`. Any idea on what way I could get along with will be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you going to use angular just for displaying the JSON as a table, then it would be a overkill.

you can do it in plain javascript itself easily.

We can create each cell of the table with javascript and append it into a table dynamically.

```
function showInfo() {
    var table = document.getElementById('info');
    
    info.forEach(function(obj) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr'),
            col1 = document.createElement('td'),
            col2 = document.createElement('td'),
            place = document.createTextNode(obj.place),
            username = document.createTextNode(obj.username);
        col1.appendChild(place);
        col2.appendChild(username);
        row.appendChild(col1);
        row.appendChild(col2);
        table.appendChild(row);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

Here is the sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk01bz3k)

#### Update

seems forEach is not supported in IE.  here is another version which uses for loop instead of forEach construct

```
function showInfo() {
    var table = document.getElementById('info');
    for (var i=0; i< info.length; i++) {
        var obj = info[i],
            row = document.createElement('tr'),
            col1 = document.createElement('td'),
            col2 = document.createElement('td'),
            place = document.createTextNode(obj.place),
            username = document.createTextNode(obj.username);
        col1.appendChild(place);
        col2.appendChild(username);
        row.appendChild(col1);
        row.appendChild(col2);
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

Here is the updated sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk01bz3k/1/)

Comment: I don't have IE 10 to check.  But since this is plain javascript, this should work.  are there any errors in developer console?

Comment: are you saying about adding more objects to the `info` var?  if so, yes this will work...

Comment: Ah! it seems forEach is not supported by IE.  we can replace that with a for loop.  I will update the answer

Comment: If this solution helped solve the problem, consider marking it as solution, so others who come in search of this problem, will quickly be able to check the solution.

Comment: any idea what it means to `expose` a `JSON`? @Anbarasan

Comment: i am not sure what context you are asking.  one way it would mean would be, when you develop a api or service which external clients would use, then you would present the data as JSON

Answer (score 1):

You can import the data with a script tag:

```
<script src="data.json"></script>
```

And then use angularjs to display the data:

```
<script>
    angular.module('mainApp', [])
      .controller('mainCtl', function($scope) {
        $scope.info = info;
    });
</script>  


<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtl"> 
    <table border="1" width="300">
        <tr><td>Place</td><td>Username</td></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="n in info">
            <td>{{n.place}}</td>
            <td>{{n.username}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>       
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hdbu1ffs/

Comment: I understand your solution. I tried to run it using chrome, but I didn't quite get the output that the fiddle showed me. I get something like : 
|    Place          |    Username        |
|    {{n.place}}  |    {{n.username}} |

I would have shown you a screenshot, but I cant post one here.. @Mathew . Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: Probably because the angular.js file is missing, try adding the script to the top of you page. http://jsfiddle.net/s9js7ehf/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could accomplish this with Angular, and [here is a working plunker of the code below](http://plnkr.co/edit/MyDF7Sd9L1va0SIORveQ?p=preview):

**data.json**

```
[
  {
    "place": "Turkey",
    "username": "jhon"
  },
  {
    "place": "Dubai",
    "username": "bruce"
  },
  {
    "place": "Italy",
    "username": "Wayne"
  }
]
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.info = null;
  $http.get("data.json").success(function (data) {
    $scope.info = data;
  });
});
```

**View**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="thing in info">
        <td>{{thing.place}}</td>
        <td>{{thing.username}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

***you can solve easily by using angularjs:***

**in data.json:**

```
 [
        {
            "place": "Turkey",
            "username": "jhon"
        },
        {
            "place": "Dubai",
            "username": "bruce"
        }, 
        {
            "place": "Italy",
            "username": "Wayne"
        }
    ]
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('SolutionController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("data.json").then(function(infos) {
            $scope.infos = infos;
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.infos = null;
        });
    }
]);
```

**and view:**

```
<body ng-controller="SolutionController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="info in infos">
            <td data-ng-bind="info.place"></td>
            <td data-ng-bind="info.username"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```